# RTK query / Get cached data in extraReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to run some side effects every time a data for certain query changed. I was hoping I can do it outside of any of my components and avoid putting the logic in useEffect.

Let's say I want to do something once my query finished. I would then add this to my slice:

```
const mySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'myReducer',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
>! some reducers
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(someApi.endpoints.someEndpoint.matchFulfilled, (state) => {
>! Do something here
    })
  }
});
```

`someEndpoint` is being called after someone interacts with a Select input, so they can choose: `Option1` => fetch details from `someEndpoint` => extraReducer gets `matchFulfilled` and the code runs.
The problem is when the user selects `Option2`, and then goes back to `Option1`. In this case the result is taken from the cache and the code won't run. I know I can add `refetchOnMountOrArgChange` to the query, but that seems a bit hacky. I imagine extraReducers are not meant to be used that way, hence my question, what's the best way to handle such case, ideally without `useEffect`?

Comment: not to be that guy, but imo you are better off with decoupling component logic with api logic. useEffect is much tidier and readable than something somewhere in the source causing a side-effect and nobody knows what